# Entity framework core creating additional table columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to migrate a simple table but ef-core is creating additional columns which i haven't specified

Here is my model which i used to create a sql table

```
public class Transaction
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

        [MaxLength(1024)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

EF-Core is creating the following table.

How to stop EF-Core from generating CategoryName and CategoryCashFlowId columns

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Transactions",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Amount = table.Column<decimal>(nullable: false),
                    DateTimeCreated = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 1024, nullable: true),
                    CategoryId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    CategoryName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    CategoryCashFlowId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Transactions", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Transactions_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Transactions_Categories_CategoryName_CategoryCashFlowId",
                        columns: x => new { x.CategoryName, x.CategoryCashFlowId },
                        principalTable: "Categories",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "Name", "CashFlowId" },
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

Here is my fluent api code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex("Username").IsUnique();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(c => new { c.Name, c.CashFlowId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Common.Models.CashFlow>().HasData(
                new CashFlow { Id = 1, Name = "Income" },
                new CashFlow { Id = 2, Name = "Expense" }
            );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Common.Models.Category>().HasData(
                new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Food and Drinks", CashFlowId = 2 },
                new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Travel", CashFlowId = 2 },
                new Category { Id = 3, Name = "Salary", CashFlowId = 1 }
            );
        }
```

Edit 1: Category Model

```
public class Category
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// <remarks> Is Indexed with CashflowId </remarks>
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(32)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CashFlowId { get; set; }

        public CashFlow CashFlow { get; set; }

}
```

Edit 2: Added CashFlow model

```
public class CashFlow
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(32)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Edit 3: Posted my DbContext

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Common.Models.Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CashFlow> CashFlows { get; set; }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
        {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex("Username").IsUnique();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(c => new { c.Name, c.CashFlowId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Common.Models.CashFlow>().HasData(
                new CashFlow { Id = 1, Name = "Income" },
                new CashFlow { Id = 2, Name = "Expense" }
            );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Common.Models.Category>().HasData(
                new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Food and Drinks", CashFlowId = 2 },
                new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Travel", CashFlowId = 2 },
                new Category { Id = 3, Name = "Salary", CashFlowId = 1 }
            );
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why **CategoryName** and **CategoryCashFlowId** columns are getting created

Please help

Comment: Show us the definition of `Category`. It looks like EF sees a 3 column PK.

Comment: Plese add CashFlow Model and fluent api if do writed

Comment: @behroz Added CashFlow model

Answer (score 1):

> why CategoryName and CategoryCashFlowId columns are getting created

With this line: `modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(c => new { c.Name, c.CashFlowId });` You are creating a composite key for table `Category` which cannot be an `int`.

In your `Transaction` object you are trying to map a key `CategoryId` for your `Category` as stated before your composite key cannot be an `int` nether a single property just by nature of composition. So at this point `CategoryId` is not a foreign key, it's just another property.

EF core is putting the two properties you used for the primary composite key of your `Category` object in to your `Transaction` object to be used as a foreign composite key.

You can resolve this by removing the composition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your `Transaction` model has a reference (navigation property) to the `Category` model, along with a `CategoryId`. But it can't actually reference the `Category` model by the `CategoryId` because the `Category` model actually has a composite key of `Name` and `CashFlowId`. So Entity Framework adds these behind the scenes to reference it.

I think you can create an alternate key on `Category` using `CategoryId` and it would be referenced that way without creating the extra columns.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasKey(c => new { c.Name, c.CashFlowId })
    .HasAlternateKey(c => c.CategoryId);
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys

Answer (score 0):

CashFlow on Category should be virtual.

```
public virtual CashFlow CashFlow { get; set; }
```

Category should be

```
public class Category
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// <remarks> Is Indexed with CashflowId </remarks>
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(32)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Index("IX_NameCashFlowId", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        public int CashFlowId { get; set; }

        [Index("IX_NameCashFlowId", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        public CashFlow CashFlow { get; set; }

}
```

With this setup `modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey` is not needed.

Comment: How do I have a composite primary key on Name and CashflowId then ?

Comment: With `[Index("IX_NameCashFlowId", 1, IsUnique = true)]` on both properties. 'Id` should be the PK.

Answer (score 0):

when u use this config for

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(c => new { c.Name, c.CashFlowId });
```

category table primary key is Name and CashFlowId and transaction table for relation must generate these columns.